# Given two numbers n1 and n2 as input, return an array containing all the primes between n1 and n2

Tags: java, arrays

(Note that both n1 and n2 can be included in the array if they are prime) Also, the primes in the array need to be in ascending order.

```
public int[] getPrimes(int start,int stop){

      int flag=0;
      int k=0;
      int arr[] =new int[stop-start];

      if(start==1){
      for(int i=start+1; i<=stop; i++){     
      flag=0;
      for(int j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
      {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
          flag=1;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(flag==0){
      arr[k]=i;
      k++;
      }

      }
    }

      else{
      for(int i=start; i<=stop; i++){     
      flag=0;
      for(int j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
      {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
          flag=1;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(flag==0){
      arr[k]=i;
      k++;
      if(k+1==0)
      break;
      }

      }
    }
    return arr;

   }
```

Testcase Parameters

```
'1' '20' 

Testcase Expected Answer

{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}

My Answer

{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

My Answer could not limit array,any suggestion please? also if can optimize my code without using any array function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try returning trimmed array:

```
return Arrays.copyOf(arr, k);
```

instead of

```
return arr;
```

Comment: ,i am new on java array not quite familiar using trim,can you help me out.

Comment: In your `getPrimes` method change  `return arr` with `return Arrays.copyOf(arr,k);` it will return only k element

Comment: _ do i need to import any library? because its shows me error cannot find symbol
    return Arrays.copyOf(arr,k);

Comment: yes `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: checkout my answer there. hope it works as you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88693/discussion-between-rustam-and-pallavi-singh).

Answer (score 2):

In this line: `int arr[] =new int[stop-start];` you are giving the output array a size of 19 (in your example), but the problem is that you don't know how many primes there are between the 2 indexes.

The default value in an array of Int's is 0, so all of the unused index's in the array are assigned to this value.

My advise would be to instead use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of a standard array, because it's size expands as and when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`int []arr = new int[num2-num1];//an array of relatively a larger size
            for(int i=num1;i<=num2;i++){
                for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
                     result = i%j;//this will calculate the modulus 
                     if(result==0)//yes then the number is composite
                        break;
                }
               //this says that loop has executed i-1 times but factor not found 
            if(result!=0){
                    arr[count] = i;
                    count++;
                }
            }`

You should have added some comment for us to understand your code, nevertheless try this logic which will divide any number from 2 to (number-1) if it is prime then it must got to be divided

Now to solve your printing problem restrict your array from (0 to count) or till
the array has value and print the array.

Comment: your code will not run if test case start with 1.